# How to convert image from <form> and AJAX POST data to the specific server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, imagemagick

My question in topic. Some details:
Server - node.js
Convert for image - child process with image magick (script for convert - works)
URL for uploading image - specific url from VK.API ([RU](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F)) I need to attach input file=type and name=photo. How I can do it with $.ajax ? What variable I need put to data field? Or another way?

I have a form with 2 fields: text and `<input type="file" name="photo">`. After submit - data sends to express. And now: how i can work with uploaded image? Convert script waiting for correct way/to/img.

After success with convert, I receive file on my hard disk. How I can $.post to specific url with correctly (again) way/to/img and name=photo ?

Thank you!

p.s. Server side - node.js + express, convert tool - [image magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

Comment: Traditional Ajax doesn't support file uploads.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I need iframe? I haven't idea for google request =/

Comment: You can upload files via ajax/xhr in all browsers (for the most part) other than IE9 and older.  For IE9 and older, you must resort to a form submit.

Comment: There's this: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: There's also this, which I personally maintain: http://fineuploader.com